# Bing maps Licensing - Free?

Tags: bing-maps

I am running a public ecommerce website. I want to integrate bing maps into the application. I would like to know if it is free of cost,

If it is not free, how much does it cost for a month?
How can i upgrade the account?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this site https://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx

For use within your organization you have to pay for transactions per month.